# Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon cannot start a session

Tags: linux-mint, login, cinnamon, session

As of today, I cannot login into my account. I start the computer, get to the login screen, login and then this following error appears:

`Your session only lasted less than 10 seconds, if you...`

And my `~/.xsession-errors` file has this output:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...

/etc/mdm/Xsession: 21: /home/lenduya/.profile: source: not found

localuser:lenduya being added to access control list
```

`lenduya` being my username.

My setup:

- Thinkpad T430
- dualboot with Windows 10.

What I've tried:

- repair broken packages: chose advanced Ubuntu at the booting screen, selected repair broken packages
- `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`: 0 new packages installed, cinnamon already at the latest version
- `sudo apt-get update`: 0 new packages installed

What I did prior:

- no major updates today AFAIK (two packages were updated)
- computer worked normally, just VLC wouldn't start. I probed around a little bit, there was one suggestion that I should check whether `Pulse Audio` is one of the softwares that starts up automatically. So I went on to look and `Pulse Audio` wasn't among things that Startup starts with. Clicked on `Add software` but didn't find `Pulse Audio` in the list so I closed it.
- I try to restart the computer, maybe that would fix the VLC issue.
- this error occurs.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? I'd prefer if I did not have to reinstall it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Although, I'm not dual boot w/ Windows. I'm also on a ThinkPad (W550s). I did, however have some updates install over the last few days. I didn't reboot until today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's VirtualBox that is the problem.
Fix: <Ctrl><Alt><F1> to get a shell and login to the prompt.

Then:

```
    sudo apt-get remove virtualbox*
```

Credit goes to: [Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=266431&p=1449131#p1449131)

Comment: Ha! I did see a VirtualBox update go by.

Comment: Try first: `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-guest*`

Comment: This fix works even for instances not running in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

As /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so.1 was reported in the crash log,
I have tried to only remove the Virtualbox guest addiction, and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-guest-utils
```